# Interrupting Select to add another socket to watch in Python

Tags: python, tcp, winsock

I'm implementing peer-to-peer IPC using TCP in a Windows XP  application.

I'm using the `select` and `socket` modules in Python 2.6.6.

I have three TCP threads, a reading thread that typically is blocking on `select()`, a writing thread that is typically waiting on an event (the event indicates there is stuff to write to TCP) and a listening thread that accepts connections.

If I start a new connection or close a current one then I need to interrupt the read select and restart it so it listens to the newly accepted socket as well.

Under `winsock` I can call `WSACancelBlockingCall` which will interrupt the select gracefully.

So my question is this: is it possible to do all this in a pythonic way without resorting to using `poll()`?

Many thx

--DM

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how poll is different than select - they both take a timeout. Select can wait indefinitely. Both can return immediately. Whichever I use I still need to break out of the wait if I accept a new socket on a different thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try adding an extra file descriptor to your set that you use as a signaling mechanism.  You can then write to that descriptor a dummy value to cause `select` to exit.  For example:

```
my_pipe = os.pipe()
...
while True:
    ready_fds = select.select(my_read_fds + [my_pipe[0]],
                              my_write_fds, my_except_fds, timeout)
    if my_pipe[0] in ready_fds[0]:
        # Add another fd to my_read_fds, etc.
        os.read(my_pipe[0], 1)
    ...

# To interrupt the current select call and add a new fd, write to the pipe:
os.write(my_pipe[1], 'x')
```

Comment: Great answer. But that only works in unix. Under Windows select only works on winsock handles. Given your suggestion I'm guessing that because of this restriction in winsock I will actually need to call WSACancelBlockingCall.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to add comments, so I'm adding this as an answer.

Don't use `WSACancelBlockingCall`. You should use the approach from Adam Rosenfield's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660756/interrupting-select-to-add-another-socket-to-watch-in-python/4661284#4661284). Just make a pair of dummy sockets one connected to another, instead of a dummy file descriptor. Include one of that sockets in your `select()` call. When you need to interrupt the call - just write a byte into the second dummy socket.

Oh, and don't forget to read that byte back from the first socket when `select()` will return.