# Python select.select and thread that put socket in output list

Tags: python, multithreading, select

I have a problem with a Python client socket.

I need to connect to a server and I want to:

1. Send a chr if the socket doesn't receive a chr in the last 10
   seconds
2. Send back every chr that the socket receive
3. Have a thread where (asynchronously) we can decide to send a chr
   whenever we want

I try to create the script using select.select method.
Here is my code:

```
class ThreadCollector(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, s, outputs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__s = s
        self.__outputs = outputs
    def run(self):
        global message_queues
        time.sleep(12)
        message_queues.put("Y")
        self.__outputs.append(self.__s)
        time.sleep(30)

print "Start main process"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
port = 999999
s.connect((address, port))
inputs = [s]
outputs = []
message_queues = Queue.Queue()
ThreadCollector(s, outputs).start()
timeout = 10
while 1 == 1:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, timeout)
    if not (readable or writable or exceptional):
        message_queues.put("T")
        outputs.append(s)
    else:
        for socketactivated in readable:
            if socketactivated is s:
                input = s.recv(1)
                message_queues.put(input)
                outputs.append(s)
        for socketactivated in writable:
            if socketactivated is s:
                message = message_queues.get_nowait()
                s.send(messaggio)
                outputs.remove(s)
print "End main process"
```

The script works well.
If the timeout is reached, the "T" chr is immediately sent to the destination.

But I have a problem.

When the thread push chr "Y" to "message_queues" and append the socket to the output list, the script doesn't send the "Y" immediately. It sends "Y" only after timeout expires and the main script append "T" and socket to lists.

Only after this operation "select.select" wakes up knowing that there is something to send. And main script correctly sees that the output list contains two socket, and message_queues two chr ("Y" and "T").

If the thread sleeps, and the timeout is reached, the process is fine and the "T" is immediately sent after the main script fills "message_queues" and "outputs". In this case, I can see that the script return to select.select, which immediately understand that the output list has something to send.

Why can't my thread tells "select.select" that the socket has something to send? What can I write to wake up "select.select" from the thread?
Where can I put that information?

Comment: you can use a pipe or dummy socket to 'wake up' the select, like what is stated at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660756/interrupting-select-to-add-another-socket-to-watch-in-python